# How to join a byte string together? Make b'\x1D\x12' to become b'\x121D'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I just need to join the last 2 bytes of my byte string together.

I have tried to add the two together, however this does just that.. add them together. I have also tried converting this to a byte array and still cannot seem to get this to work.

```py
buf = b'\x00\x80\x03\x00\x3A\x04\x01\x1D\x12'
try1 = buf[6]+buf[5]
```

I expected to get

```py
try1 = b'\x121D'
```

I actually got:

```py
try1 = b'\x12\x1D'
```

I have also tried:

```py
buf_ret = b'\x00\x80\x03\x00\x3A\x04\x01\x1D\x12'
number1 = buf_ret[len(buf_ret)-2:]
number1 = number1.hex()
number1 = number1[2:]+number1[:2]

number2 = b'\x121d'
number2 = number2.hex()
```

The output would be:

```py
number1
'121d'
number2
'123164'
```

As you can see, these two numbers are not equal.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: The `\x00`s are just hexadecimal notation for each individual byte. Concatenating the bytes `1D` and `12` will thus be represented as `\x1D\x12`. If you need a certain different notation, convert your bytes from a bytes object to a hexadecimal string and go from there.

Comment: `b'\x121d'` is not the same thing as `b'\x12\x1d'`. The former is equivalent to `b'\x12\x31\x64'` since a literal ASCII `1` has value 0x31 and `d` is 0x64 (see `man ascii` if you're on a UNIX like OS). You need to spend more time reading about byte strings and their representations.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't specify what you want to do with the result it's hard to understand why you want them formatted that way or whether it's the binary value or string you're after.

If you simply want the string representation of the concatenation you could do something like this:

```
>>> buf[-1].encode("hex") + buf[-2].encode("hex")
>>> '121d'
```

Comment: I had tried what you suggested and was given 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: .encode() is a method in the string class. Try str(buf[-1]).encode("hex") + str(buf[-2]).encode("hex")

Comment: @Framental you wrote "The numeric value of b'\x121D' and b'\x12\x1D' are both the same." That is not true.